# How to get value from cache service in a component

Tags: angular

I am trying to store the response of a service call so that it can be used in other parts of my app. This is what I have tried so far but am stuck in getting the values.

Admin Service

```
  getOfferTemplates() {
    const corporateId = this._storeService.getStoredData().profile.CorporateId;
    const token = this._storeService.getStoredData().id_token;
    const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`);
    const options = { headers: headers };
    const url = `${this._templatesUrl}/offers/${corporateId}`;
    return this._http.get(url, options);
  }
```

UsersCachService

```
  public allTemplates: any = [];
  getOfferTemplates(){
    this._loader.start();
    this._subscriptions.push(this._adminService.getOfferTemplates()
    .subscribe((resp) => {
      this._loader.stop();
      this.allTemplates = resp;
   }, (error) => {
      this._loader.stop();
      this._errorService.openErrorPopup('Failed to get the offer template.');
    }
    ))
  }
```

Component

```
  validateName() {
   console.log(this.usersService.getOfferTemplates());
  }
```

How do I get the allTemplates value in the component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do :

```
this.usersService.allTemplates
```

or create a getter like:

```
 get allTemplate(){ 
   return this.allTemplates;
 }
```